# Dolphin context menu exec command, cp will duplicate selected folder if already copied

Tags: command-line, scripts, rsync, dolphin, context-menu

So I'm trying to automate some tasks and I'm making some dolphin ServiceMenus.

```
Exec=for file in %f; do new_path=$(echo "$file" | sed "s|^/home/$(whoami)||"); mkdir -p ~/Dropbox/.Home"$(dirname "$new_path")" && cp -pur "$file" ~/Dropbox/.Home"$new_path"; done
```

The above line will work perfectly fine for what I want the first time. But when I try to copy/update the same folder again, it will just duplicate itself at the destination.

> ~/Dropbox/Documents/SelectedFolder
>
> ~/Dropbox/Documents/SelectedFolder/SelectedFolder

I've also tried

```
Exec=for file in %f; do new_path=$(echo "$file" | sed "s|^/home/$(whoami)||"); mkdir -p ~/Dropbox/.Home"$(dirname "$new_path")" && rsync -r -t -p -o -g -v --delete -s "$file"/ ~/Dropbox/.Home"$new_path"; done
```

But rsync wont work for files using the slash after "$file".

What I really want to achieve is just copying selected files and folders from dolphin to a destination folder with /home/user trimmed from the destination folder structure.

**--- EDIT: ---**

This is supposed to be a .desktop file which works as a dolphin context menu where I click on whatever folder or file I want so it will be copied to `~Dropbox/.Home` preserving folder structure. Lets say I want to copy (cp -pur) `/home/user/.local/share/applications` to `/home/user/Dropbox/.Home`. The new (copied) files folder structure will be `/home/user/Dropbox/.Home/home/user/.local/share/applications` while what I need is `/home/user/Dropbox/.Home/.local/share/applications`. While the "/home/user" trim on the above code example works, as well as copying and updating individual files, what doesnt work is trying to update an already copied folder on the destination by running the same command again (from the context menu) which will leave the destination files intact and create a new copy of the same folder inside of it.

first time copy is like this

> `/home/user/Dropbox/.Home/.local/share/applications`

trying to copy again to update will be like this

> `/home/user/Dropbox/.Home/.local/share/applications/applications`

Comment: Do you always copy directories or is this also supposed to work for individual files? Can you gie us some examples of each of the possible use cases? Show us the folder structure you have and what you expect after the copy.

Comment: @terdon i tried to explain. edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, added `if` to identify is selected item is file or folder and this is the code that worked without any problems

```
Exec=for file in %f; do if [ -d "$file" ]; then new_path=$(dirname "$file" | sed "s|^$HOME||"); mkdir -p ~/Dropbox/.Home"$new_path" && cp -pur "$file"/ ~/Dropbox/.Home"$new_path"; fi; if [ -f "$file" ]; then new_path=$(dirname "$file" | sed "s|^$HOME||"); mkdir -p ~/Dropbox/.Home"$new_path" && cp -pur "$file" ~/Dropbox/.Home"$new_path"; fi; done
```